# Android callback for a coroutine flow is not fired

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have a service where the data is backed by a MutableLiveData and exposed to outside through a flow.

```
@ApplicationScope
@Singleton
class UserProfileServiceImpl : UserProfileService {

    private var userLiveData: MutableLiveData<UserProfile?> = MutableLiveData()

    override fun currentUser() = userLiveData.value

    override fun updatePoints(points: Int) {
       val user = currentUser()
           ?: throw IllegalAccessException("user is not authenticated")

       user.points = points
       userLiveData.postValue(user)
    }

    override suspend fun currentUserFlow(): Flow<UserProfile?> =
        callbackFlow {
            userLiveData.observeForever {
                offer(it)
            }
        }
}
```

Then I listen for changes in the viewmodel of a fragment and the callback is not getting called

```
class ViewModel: ViewModel() {
    fun startListeningToService() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            profileService.currentUserFlow().collect {
                // This is not getting fired
                // Send data to another liveData that the activity is listening to
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Am i making this complicated? feels like a lot of layers of passing
   data from 1 point to another? Is there really an advantage to using a
   Flow here? it feels like just using the LiveData across would be much
   simpler and doesn't require translating between the two
2. Even if This is not the best design, why is the callback not fired?

Comment: Just an FYI, MutableLiveData doesn't update the value if the View is not currently visible. Make sure that is not a problem for you. I'll attach some reference if I find one related to the point I made above.

Comment: Regarding your first question: yes. The main advantage of Flow over LiveData is that it limits dependencies on Android-specific APIs, but that’s wasted if you make it depend on LiveData anyway. StateFlow can be used instead of LiveData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you are using the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx` artifact, you can simply use `liveData.asFlow()`

If you do want to roll your custom implementation using `callbackFlow`, you need to call `awaitClose{...}` inside the flow builder, otherwise it will be treated as completed immediately.

```
override suspend fun currentUserFlow(): Flow<UserProfile?> =
        callbackFlow {
            val observer = Observer<UserProfile?>{
                offer(it)
            }
            userLiveData.observeForever(observer)
            awaitClose{
                // called when the flow is no longer collected, e.g. the collecting 
                // CoroutineScope has been cancelled
                userLiveData.removeObserver(observer)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you this answers all my questions. It sounds like I forget about flow and build everything on live data, and when I need to use it I simply provide it as a flow